# How to serialize a CountVectorizer with a custom tokenize function with joblib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I use a CountVectorizer with a custom tokenize method. When I serialize it, then unserialize it, I get the following error message :

```
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

How can I "serialize" the `tokenize` method ?

Here is a small example :

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.snowball import FrenchStemmer
stemmer = FrenchStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems

tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words=stopwords.words('french'), ngram_range=(1,1))

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=0.02, hidden_layer_sizes=(400, 50))

pipeline = Pipeline([("tfidf", tfidf_vec),
                ("MLP", clf)])

joblib.dump(pipeline,"../models/classifier.pkl")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

joblib (and pickle which it uses under the hood) serializes functions this way: it just remembers a path to import a function from - module and function name. So if you define a function in an interactive session, there is no place to import this function from; it is destroyed as soon as process exits.

To make serialization work put this code to a Python module (save it to a .py file), and make sure this module is available (importable) when you're calling `joblib.load`.