# python cannot find method inside the same .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python cannot find method inside the same module

**model.py**

```
def tokenize(original_text):
    return [word for word in deepcut.tokenize(original_text) if word.lower() not in stop_list]

#create transformer        
bow_transformer1 = CountVectorizer(analyzer=tokenize).fit(trainset1['text'])

#save transformer
joblib.dump(bow_transformer1, 'CountVectorizer1.pkl')
```

**use_model.py**

```
def tokenize(original_text):
    return [word for word in deepcut.tokenize(original_text) if word.lower() not in stop_list]

def preprocess(data):
  bow_transformer1=joblib.load('CountVectorizer1.pkl')
  result = bow_transformer1.transform(data)
  return result
```

And when I use use_model.py in another .py file:

```
import use_model as model
model.preprocess(data)
```

It says *module '**main**' has no attribute 'tokenize'*

Comment: use different name instead of import "use_model as model" . Try using import use_model as model1 or any other name and then use model1.preprocess(data)

Comment: You are using the same name tokenize for your method and also you are calling deepcut.tokenize. So it must be a conflict of name, use different name for your tokenize method and it should work.

Comment: pickle will not store the `tokenize` method in the `CountVectorizer1.pkl`

Comment: @Sam I changed method name to 'cutWord' and save to pickle again. And also did change to model1. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi I understand that so i also put the method inside use_model.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by follow the answer of [How to serialize a CountVectorizer with a custom tokenize function with joblib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017808/how-to-serialize-a-countvectorizer-with-a-custom-tokenize-function-with-joblib)